Effects of turbulence on black hole accretion disks
Most of the analytical studies of accretion disks around black holes usually ignore the effects of turbulence. However, results of numerical simulations suggest that turbulence plays a crucial role in dynamics of accretion disks.
Is it possible to include the effects of turbulence in analytical studies of black hole accretion disks to understand how turbulence changes flow topologies and shock solutions (if shock waves are formed)?
